# MKMapView doesn't display tiles on highest zoom - appears to be related to iOS 6.1.4

Tags: iphone, ios, mkmapview, ios6.1

I'm working on an app that is heavily GPS-based.  Everything worked fantastically, specifically meaning my app's display of map tiles worked great, seemingly until I updated my iPhone5 (test device) to iOS 6.1.4.  Yes, I know that 6.1.4 supposedly only touched audio profiles, but this failure to load map tiles certainly coincided with my phone's OS upgrade.

Ever since I updated, *not a single application* on my phone (any that presumably use MKMapView), except Apple's Maps app, will load any tiles when I attempt to zoom in to the max level.  The tiles change to the gray grids with the Ø symbol.

FYI - when debugging my app, mapViewDidFailLoadingMap:withError: never fires, so the phone doesn't think it has a problem.  It's almost as if they are the tiles Apple is sending to the phone.

Anyway, I tested this on another iPhone5, which had the same problems (and was also updated to 6.1.4), and an iPhone4 and iPad 2 Retina, which did NOT show the symptoms.

Obviously, for my app, I could restrict the max zoom level to get around this, but I'm more concerned about an issue that may not be resolved until another OS update, while restricting the user's/app's capabilities in order to mask the bug.

Has anyone else seen this happen on their own devices, or heard about this happening? I'd think that if this was actually related to 6.1.4, people would be freaking out all over the web, but my web searches turn up nothing.
Other thoughts?

Thanks!